# How do I convert from a wchar_t* to a wstring?

Tags: c++, wchar-t, wstring

Or how to I initialize a wstring using a wchar_t*?

I tried something like this, but it's not quite working.
I'm given an LPVOID and it points to a wchar_t pointer.
I just want to get it into a wstring so I can use some normal string functions on it.

```
LPVOID lpOutBuffer = NULL;
//later in code this is initialized this way
lpOutBuffer = new WCHAR[dwSize/sizeof(WCHAR)];
//fills up the buffer
doStuff(lpOutBuffer, &dwSize);
//try to convert it to a wstring
wchar_t* t =  (wchar_t*)lpOutBuffer;
wstring responseHeaders = wstring(t);

printf("This prints response headers: \n%S", t);
printf("This prints nothing: \n%S", responseHeaders);
```

doStuff is really a call to [WinHttpQueryHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I just changed it to make it easier to understand my example.

Comment: Should work - `wstring` has a constructor for that. What do you get? Also, is the buffer null-terminated?

Comment: I updated the code with what's happening to initialize the pointer. I'm new to c++ so I'm still wrapping my head around pointers and such. I don't know if the the wchar_t is null terminated. I'm calling the WinHttpQueryHeaders Funtion - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102(v=vs.85).aspx I couldn't tell if it was null terminating the buffer.

Comment: @ScArcher2: What does "it's not quite working" mean?

Comment: @DrewDormann The responseHeaders wstring is empty when i attempt to print it out. If I print the wchar_t it prints out what I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the `wstring` object to `printf` is not going to work. Rephrase the second `prinf` line as

```
printf("This prints nothing: \n%S", responseHeaders.c_str());
```

c_str() gives you a `const` pointer to the underlying string data.

Comment: This is where my problem was. Thank you!

Comment: @ScArcher2 You should see if your compiler has printf format checking so you can avoid this error.

Comment: Reference to  WinHttpQueryHeaders suggests Visual C++. It does not.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev is correct. I'm using Visual Studio. At least now I know to check the type I'm passing to printf. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

If the `LPVOID` points to a `wchar_t` ***pointer*** as you say, your level of indirection is wrong.

```
LPVOID lpOutBuffer;
wchar_t** t =  (wchar_t**)lpOutBuffer;
wstring responseHeaders = wstring(*t);
```

**Edit: Question has changed.  This answer no longer applies.**

Comment: I believe I misspoke I corrected my example, since I don't know what I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

Again, too complicated. Just do this:

```
std::wstring TheNewWideString = std::wstring(TheOldWideCharacterTPointer);
```

It works directly for me on Microsoft Windows with C++11 and CodeBlocks.